# How to fetch values of a column into CLOB variable?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to pass a value of a single INTEGER column inside a CLOB variable so I can do the IN operation (the size of the output of a column is unknown), but I got an error and now I am stuck. First I was trying to use the SELECT statement after IN, but I found out it doesn't work like that in PL/SQL. So, in the nutshell, I want to be able to check the primary key in a table and if it doesn't exist update an existing record with a new value, but if it already exists I shouldn't be able to do that.

> The DoGood Donor application contains a page that allows
> administrators to change the ID assigned to a donor in the DD_DONOR
> table. Create a PL/SQL block to handle this task. Include
> exception-handling code to address an error raised by attempting to
> enter a duplicate donor ID. If this error occurs, display the message
> “This ID is already assigned.” Test the code by changing donor ID 305.

Here is a table I work with.
DD_DONOR

```
Name      Null?    Type         
--------- -------- ------------ 
IDDONOR   NOT NULL NUMBER(4)    
FIRSTNAME          VARCHAR2(15) 
LASTNAME           VARCHAR2(30) 
TYPECODE           CHAR(1)      
STREET             VARCHAR2(40) 
CITY               VARCHAR2(20) 
STATE              CHAR(2)      
ZIP                VARCHAR2(9)  
PHONE              VARCHAR2(10) 
FAX                VARCHAR2(10) 
EMAIL              VARCHAR2(25) 
NEWS               CHAR(1)      
DTENTERED          DATE
```

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE
    all_ids clob;
    newID DD_DONOR.IDDONOR%TYPE;
    fname DD_DONOR.FIRSTNAME%TYPE;
    lname DD_DONOR.LASTNAME%TYPE;    
    CURSOR id IS
    SELECT IDDONOR FROM DD_DONOR;   
BEGIN
    newID := 305;
    fname := 'Thomas';
    lname := 'Sheer';
    
    OPEN id;
    FETCH id BULK COLLECT INTO all_ids;

    IF id%NOTFOUND THEN
        UPDATE DD_DONOR
        SET IDDONOR = newID
        WHERE FIRSTNAME = fname AND LASTNAME = lname;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(fname || ' ' || lname || ' ' || 'New ID: ' || newID);
    ELSIF id%FOUND THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This ID is already assigned.');
    END IF;

    CLOSE id;
END;
```

And here is the error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 14, column 32:
PLS-00497: cannot mix between single row and multi-row (BULK) in INTO list
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

This code that I created in the beginning compiles, but doesn't do anything to the table, so I've abandoned it:

```
DECLARE
    newID DD_DONOR.IDDONOR%TYPE;
    fname DD_DONOR.FIRSTNAME%TYPE;
    lname DD_DONOR.LASTNAME%TYPE;
    
BEGIN
    newID := 305;
    fname := 'Thomas';
    lname := 'Sheer';
    
    UPDATE DD_DONOR
    SET IDDONOR = newID
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT IDDONOR
                      FROM DD_DONOR
                      WHERE FIRSTNAME = fname AND LASTNAME = lname);
    EXCEPTION 
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This ID is already assigned.');
END;
```

The output:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Another version that doesn't work:

```
DECLARE
    newID DD_DONOR.IDDONOR%TYPE;
    fname DD_DONOR.FIRSTNAME%TYPE;
    lname DD_DONOR.LASTNAME%TYPE;
    
BEGIN
    newID := 305;
    fname := 'Thomas';
    lname := 'Sheer';
    
    IF (SELECT IDDONOR FROM DD_DONOR
        WHERE FIRSTNAME = fname AND LASTNAME = lname) = newID
        THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This ID is already assigned.');
    ELSE
        UPDATE DD_DONOR
        SET IDDONOR = newID
        WHERE FIRSTNAME = fname AND LASTNAME = lname;
    END IF;
END;
```

This one kind works, but again, doesn't output an error message that the ID is taken:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 100000
DECLARE
    newID DD_DONOR.IDDONOR%TYPE;
    fname DD_DONOR.FIRSTNAME%TYPE;
    lname DD_DONOR.LASTNAME%TYPE;     
    CURSOR id IS    
    SELECT IDDONOR FROM DD_DONOR
    WHERE FIRSTNAME = fname AND LASTNAME = lname;       
BEGIN
    newID := 305;
    fname := 'Thomas';
    lname := 'Sheer';    
    OPEN id;
    IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
        UPDATE DD_DONOR
        SET IDDONOR = newID
        WHERE FIRSTNAME = fname AND LASTNAME = lname;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(fname || ' ' || lname || ' ' || 'New ID: ' || newID);
    ELSIF SQL%FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This ID is already assigned.');
    END IF;
    CLOSE id;
END;
```

This one doesn't work, but I like it. It looks like it should work.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 100000
DECLARE
    newID DD_DONOR.IDDONOR%TYPE;
    fname DD_DONOR.FIRSTNAME%TYPE;
    lname DD_DONOR.LASTNAME%TYPE;    
    CURSOR id IS    
    SELECT IDDONOR FROM DD_DONOR
    WHERE FIRSTNAME = fname AND LASTNAME = lname;    
    all_IDs DD_DONOR%rowtype;    
BEGIN
    newID := 305;
    fname := 'Thomas';
    lname := 'Sheer';    
    OPEN id;    
    LOOP
        FETCH id into all_IDs;
        UPDATE DD_DONOR
        SET IDDONOR = newID
        WHERE FIRSTNAME = fname AND LASTNAME = lname;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(fname || ' ' || lname || ' ' || 'New ID: ' || newID);          
        EXIT WHEN id%FOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This ID is already assigned.');
    END LOOP; 
    CLOSE id;
END;
```

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 15, column 9:
PLS-00394: wrong number of values in the INTO list of a FETCH statement
ORA-06550: line 15, column 9:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

Comment: There are quite a few issues with both pieces of code.  I'm struggling to understand the problem you're trying to solve.  Posting some sample data and expected results is often quite helpful.  I assume you are a student and this is an assignment of some sort.  Normally, the goal would be to accept as input an `idDonor`, `firstName`, and `lastName` and to update the `firstName` and `lastName` columns for the specified `idDonor` if that row already exists.  Updating the primary key of a table is almost never done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this piece of code:

```
DECLARE
    newID DD_DONOR.IDDONOR%TYPE;
    oldID DD_DONOR.IDDONOR%TYPE;
    fname DD_DONOR.FIRSTNAME%TYPE;
    lname DD_DONOR.LASTNAME%TYPE;    
BEGIN
    newID := 305;
    fname := 'Thomas';
    lname := 'Sheer';    
    select
        iddonor
    into
        oldId
    from
        dd_donor
    WHERE iddonor = newId;
    dbms_output.put_line('This ID is already assigned');
exception
    when NO_DATA_FOUND then
        UPDATE DD_DONOR
        SET IDDONOR = newID
        WHERE FIRSTNAME = fname AND LASTNAME = lname;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(fname || ' ' || lname || ' ' || 'New ID: ' || newID); 
END;
/
```

If you want to stick to your approach with cursor here is the changes to your initial script:

Changes are in :

all_ids DD_DONOR.IDDONOR%TYPE - no need of CLOB as you expect only one record with this ID.

Declaration and Call of cursor - parameter added so you are able to search for a specific id

```
DECLARE
    all_ids DD_DONOR.IDDONOR%TYPE;
    newID DD_DONOR.IDDONOR%TYPE;
    fname DD_DONOR.FIRSTNAME%TYPE;
    lname DD_DONOR.LASTNAME%TYPE;    
    CURSOR id(newID in DD_DONOR.IDDONOR%TYPE) IS
    SELECT IDDONOR FROM DD_DONOR where iddonor = newID;   
BEGIN
    newID := 305;
    fname := 'Thomas';
    lname := 'Sheer';
    
    OPEN id(newId);
    FETCH id  INTO all_ids;

    IF id%NOTFOUND THEN
        UPDATE DD_DONOR
        SET IDDONOR = newID
        WHERE FIRSTNAME = fname AND LASTNAME = lname;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(fname || ' ' || lname || ' ' || 'New ID: ' || newID);
    ELSIF id%FOUND THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This ID is already assigned.');
    END IF;

    CLOSE id;
END;
/
```

Thanks

Comment: Brilliant! It never occurred to me to use the newID and the oldID of the same type for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Your `id` is a `NUMBER`. Your `all_ids` is a `CLOB`, which is basically a very large string field. The `IN` clause in a query works on an explicit list of discrete values; it's not a string search kind of thing. What you probably want is a collection.

`IN` works like:

```
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

the list must be of fixed length. It can also work like:

```
WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM table2 )
```

I can't quite tell what you're trying to do. Your second query will update **every** row in the table to `newID`, which is almost certainly not what you want. How do you identify the row you are you trying to update if `fname` and `lname` don't exist in the table already?